# How to override existing '/api/products/' to return more fields in Django-osacr-api?

Tags: django, django-oscar

[Django-oscar-api-override setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmPWu.png)

I am new to Oscar Api, And I need to added extra fields to the default '/api/products' response.

Additional fields to add:

description,
meta_title,
meta_description,
rating,
attributes

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_class

from rest_framework import serializers
from oscarapi.serializers import checkout, product
from oscarapi.serializers.product import (
    ProductImageSerializer, ProductLinkSerializer)


class MyProductLinkSerializer(ProductLinkSerializer):
    images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta(ProductLinkSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'title', 'images', 'rating', 'meta_title', 'meta_description')
```

I tried the above code from documentation to see if it overrides. But no luck. Can you please help to add additional fields to the default response ? or point me any sample project repo where you they overrided default response.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the [documentation](https://django-oscar-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/customizing_oscarapi.html#configuration) for how to tell Oscar API to use your custom class? There is no evidence of this in the code you've posted above.

Comment: Hi @solarissmoke.. yes but made a silly error, I followed the instruction in the documentation to add custom classes, but made a mistake in referencing the  folder in 'OSCARAPI_OVERRIDE_MODULES'. Its working now as expected. Thank you for pointing out.